# Efficiently rendering a large number of Redux Form Fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm having a table of employees and their monthly working hours day by day. Here we can update all the employees hours values in bulk.

A simple math for the current month: 30 days x 50 employees will result in 1500 mounted Redux Form Fields.

Each time a Field is being mounted, Redux Form will dispatch an action for registering the Field in the Redux store. Therefore 1500 events are dispatched.

Debugging with Chrome->Performance tool, I found out that the whole process from mounting through dispatching to rendering the Fields takes about ~4 seconds:

[image: Performance cost]

The above performance score is based on the following simple working example I've created with React, Redux, Redux Form, Reselect:

```js
/* ----------------- SAMPLE DATA GENERATION - START ----------------- */
const generateEmployees = length =>
  Array.from({ length }, (v, k) => ({
    id: k + 1,
    name: `Emp ${k + 1}`,
    hours: [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]
  }))

const employees = generateEmployees(50)
/* ----------------- SAMPLE DATA GENERATION - END ------------------- */

/* --------------------- INITIALIZATION - START --------------------- */
const { reduxForm, Field, reducer: formReducer } = ReduxForm
const { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } = Redux
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux
const { createSelector } = Reselect

// Creating the Reducers
const employeesReducer = (state = employees) => state
const reducers = {
  form: formReducer,
  employees: employeesReducer
}

// Custom logger.
// The idea here is log all the dispatched action,
// in order to illustrate the problem with many registered fields better.
const logger = ({ getState }) => {
  return next => action => {
    console.log("Action: ", action)
    return next(action)
  }
}

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)
/* --------------------- INITIALIZATION - END ----------------------- */

const renderEmployees = employees =>
  employees.map(employee => {
    return (
      <tr key={employee.id}>
        <td>{employee.id}</td>
        <td>{employee.name}</td>
        {employee.hours.map((hour, day) => (
          <td key={day}>
            <Field component="input" name={`${employee.id}_${day}`} />
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    )
  })

const FormComponent = ({ employees, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Employees working hours for November (11.2018)</h2>
      <p>
        <button type="submit">Update all</button>
      </p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            {Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => (
              <th key={k + 1}>{`${k + 1}.11`}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {renderEmployees(employees)}
      </table>
    </form>
  )
}

const Form = reduxForm({
  form: "workingHours",
  onSubmit: submittedValues => {
    console.log({ submittedValues })
  }
})(FormComponent)

const getInitialValues = createSelector(
  state => state.employees,
  users =>
    users.reduce((accumulator, employee) => {
      employee.hours.forEach(
        (hour, day) => (accumulator[`${employee.id}_${day}`] = hour)
      )

      return accumulator
    }, {})
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  employees: state.employees,
  initialValues: getInitialValues(state)
})

const App = connect(mapStateToProps)(Form)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

input {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.5.4/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.5.4/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.4/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-form/6.7.0/redux-form.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/3.0.1/reselect.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

**So am I doing something inefficient and wrong with Redux Form or rendering a large number of Fields at once is bottleneck and I should take a different approach (pagination, lazy loading, etc.)?**

Answer (score 3):

Existing open-source form libraries seem to not work well when getting into this kind of complexity. We implemented a number of optimisations by building our own form library, but it's possible that one or more of these ideas you may be able to use with redux form.

We mount a multitude of form & other redux attached components (in the order of thousands), which all do validation when they get mounted. Our architecture required all components to be mounted at once. Each component may need to update the state multiple times when they get mounted. This is not quick, but these are the optimisations we used to make this ***seem*** quick for 1000+ controls:

- Each component mounts in a way which checks if it *really* needs to dispatch something right now, or if it can wait until later. If the value in the state is wrong, or the current value is invalid - it will still cause a dispatch, otherwise it will defer other updates for later (like when the user focuses it).
- Implemented a batch reducer which can process multiple actions in a single dispatch. This means if a component does need to perform several actions on mount, at most it will only send 1 dispatch message instead of one dispatch per action.
- Debouncing react re-renders using a redux batch middleware. This means that react will be triggered to render less often when a big redux update is happening. We trigger listeners on the leading and the falling edge of redux updates, which means that react will update on the first dispatch, and every 500-1000ms after that until there are no more updates happening. This improved performance for us a lot, but depending on how your controls work, this can also make it look a bit laggy (see next item for solution)
- Local control state. Each form control has a local state and responds to user interaction immediately, and will lazily update the redux state when the user tabs out of the control. This makes things seem fast and results in less redux updates. (redux updates are expensive!!)

I'm not sure any of this will help you, and I'm not even sure that the above was smart or recommended - but it worked really well for us and I hope it can give you some ideas.

**Also, if you can get away with mounting less components (pagination etc), you definitely should do that instead. We were limited in our choices by some early architecture choices and were forced to press on and this is what we came up with.**

Comment: Thank you for the great and detailed answer! To be honest, I don't want to create a **custom** form implementation, because there are a lot of things, these have to be considered and implemented later. For example: errors handling, validations, initial values setting up and etc. Using Redux-Form you have these features by default. However, if I can't find a better approach or the business requirements don't allow us having a pagination, then I'll try to implement a simple form abstraction, only for this case. Thank you! :)

Comment: In an application i'm working on atm, we had to switch to `formik` for this exact reason. The transition is pretty chill

Comment: @joviDeCroock Does it implement some of the things i mentioned here? To me it looks like a very very simple form library which would work good if you didnt have many requirements but would be unsuitable for a more complicated enterprisey form with hundreds of conditions and validations.

Comment: For example an issue with redux-form is registerring. Which is something that doesn't need to happen in a normal State way. There are many things that the non decoupled approach saves time on.

Comment: @joviDeCroock You didn't explain why formik was better than alternative solutions or how it relates to optimising the performance of a large set of inputs, and you still haven't.

Comment: To be honest, using `formik` as a starting point, sounds a good idea to me. For advanced cases, I guess it can be extended somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized I used it in a project where I was capturing dozen of events. The list is growing and growing and this component helped me render all of them. I'm not sure how Redux Form works but if it is based on mounting then I guess this is a good option.

Comment: Won't it be quite hard to virtualize FormGroups since that implies their height dissapearing? If your groups have a pre-defined height it's possible.

Comment: It's a good approach, unless you have a nested columns / rows. In the Question I've provided a simple flat table example which can be implemented with `react-virtualized`, but my real use-case has a nested table, which is non-compliant with the library.